# Elasticsearch Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I need some help to query a field in my index.  This field will have data such as:

> GB10
>   GB40
>   GB45
>   UK09
>   UK40

If I have the query:

`"Show me the code GB 40"`

(**note the space between GB and 40**)

I would like the JSON to return the result for the `GB40` as the top result.  Can anyone help with how I can I go about doing this and any changes I might need to make? I haven't set the field as analysed yet.

Comment: Makes no sense why you are trying to do so.

Comment: Can you please explain your use case?

Comment: can you please show your query and mappings, that will make it easy to help

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I will have a search box which the user will use to ask questions, so in some cases they may enter GB40 correctly, but sometimes the could enter it with a a space like GB 40.  So that's why I wanted to find a way for the right results to come back.

Comment: @user3775217 I've just been playing about with this trying to think how to do it, I haven't got any finalised query or mappings.  If you check my previous comment hopefully that might give a bit more insight.

Comment: Just one other thing, the data will be pulled in from a mySQL DB by log stash.  I know that the data could be formatted to add a space, but in this case it may not always be a two letter code followed by digits, so I don't think it can formatted easily.

Comment: ok, if you cannot manipulate the data models before pushing them to elastic via logstash, you can then update the mappings to use word_delimeter filter tokenizer. Please refer to my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you have words with such pattern then you might want to exploit `split on letter-number transitions: "SD500" → "SD", "500"` using [word_delimiter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html) tokenizer filter in elastic.

You can split the word on letter-word transition using this filter to have both letter and number part of the word stored seperately on inverted index. Neverthless this will also keep a copy of exact value on index.

Please refer the mappings and queries below

```
PUT testindex_48
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {

                "word_delimiter_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "word_delimiter"
                    ],
                    "ignore_case": true,
                    "preserve_original": true
                }
            },
             "filter":{

            "word_delimiter":{
              "type":"word_delimiter",
              "generate_word_parts":true,
              "preserve_original": true
            }
        }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "table1": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "word_delimiter_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

POST testindex_48/table1
{
  "title" : "EC450"
}

POST testindex_48/table1/_search
{
  "query": {"bool": {"must": [
    {"term": {
      "title": {
        "value": "450"
      }
    }}
  ]}}
}

POST testindex_48/table1/_search
{
  "query": {"bool": {"must": [
    {"term": {
      "title": {
        "value": "ec"
      }
    }}
  ]}}
}


POST testindex_48/table1/_search
{
  "query": {"bool": {"must": [
    {"term": {
      "title": {
        "value": "ec450"
      }
    }}
  ]}}
}
```

Now your usecase if user enters "EC 450", you can build a similar query like the follows.

Comment: thanks this sounds great, I will test it out. Just one other thing to make it more confusing, in the same field coming from the mySQL db there may be data that's just letters e.g aaabbb, where there's no easy way to identify how to split it in a mapping. If the user were to search 'aaa bbb' with a space, would it just be case of using some sort of fuzzy matching to get the result data?  Or is there a better way I could go about it?

Comment: then i would use n-gram tokenizer to token the entire string to keep things simple instead of diving into fuzzy matching.https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html. thanks

Comment: fantastic advice! Thanks for the help, I've tested everything out now.